# SCSS Opacity transition cross-fade

Tags: css, sass, less, opacity

I am adding classes dynamically to a table based on when that data is loaded or loading.

I have:

```
@keyframes row-loading {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
}

@keyframes row-loaded {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
```

Used by:

```
tr {
      height: 45px;
      &.loading {
        -webkit-animation: row-loading 0.8s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      }
      &.loaded {
        -webkit-animation: row-loaded 0.8s;
      }
...
```

The problem is, if the data loads too quickly, the .loaded class is applied and opacity jumps to 0, rather than starting from when .loading left it.

How can I get this to start fading in from where the previous class left off?

Comment: `&.loaded { opacity: 0.3;  -webkit-animation: row-loaded 0.8s;}`

Answer (score 1):

you can try transition instead of animation like so

```
tr {
  height: 45px;
  opacity:1;
  transition: opacity 0.8s;

  &.loading {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
}
```

when you start loading data add "loading" class to "tr" so a transition will begin to opacity:1 to opacity:0.3; and when data finishes loading just remove "loading" class it will return back to its original opacity